# C++ Addition within a Macro Function Argument

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have this snippet of C++ code from an exam. We are just suppose to write out what the output of the program is, I assumed the output would be '20', but the output is '10'. Why is this?

```
#define func(x) (x*x)-x

int i=3;

int main() {
    cout  << func(i+2) << endl;
}
```

If I put the i+2 in brackets like so:

```
cout  << func( (i+2) ) << endl;
```

The output is '20' as assumed it would be.

How does C++ process this code that makes it return 10 not 20?

Comment: Macros just do text substitution, `func` is not a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just how macros work. It's pure text substitution. So `func(i+2)` expands as:

```
(i+2*i+2)-i+2
```

which is to say:

```
2*i + 4
```

This is why typically macros would be written by excessively parenthesizing the arguments:

```
#define func(x) (((x)*(x))-(x))
```

But really, this is why you should strongly prefer functions to macros. While parenthesizing the arguments would fix the usage in `func(i+2)`, it still wouldn't fix the usage in `func(++i)` - which while being a straightforward expression if `func` were a function is undefined behavior with the macro.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know this, I guess professor was just trying to catch us out by calling it 'func'.

Answer (score 4):

Because the brackets aren't there.

The macro expands to

```
(i+2*i+2)-i+2
```

And it all goes wrong from there. An inline function instead of a macro would just work.

Lessons to be learned: (1) Always parenthesise inside macro definitions. (2) DON'T USE MACROS IN C++!

Comment: Thanks also. Wasn't aware of this.